# How to retain the values selected in a popup when the popup is reloaded again in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a dynamic form by which user can select or create queries dynamically . There is scenario where i want that once the user selects some of the criteria in the popup and clicks on RUN , and when open the popup again , it should retain the selected values .

I tried storing the array value in LocalStorage while closing the popup and loading the array value by checking if localstorage is not empty but that didnt work . Can anyone help me in achieving this ?

Comment: So first time when clicking on `OpenAlertDialog` button, this form dialog will display, and when you click on run button from form dialog, the dialog will be closed, and again you click on `OpenAlertDialog` then what have you previously added data inside form will be shown to you again, ? Right ? Is this your want the way of doing it ?

Comment: Yes correct , first time it will display only a single row , but when opened for second time , it should retain the values selected which were previously added before clicking run .

Comment: let me see and check it out.

Comment: Yes absolutely @GaurangDhorda

Comment: Thank you :) . https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-5hbcir?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.ts check it out here is this working for you or not ?

Comment: Hey , its retaining only a single row , if a user adds multiple rows by clicking + , can that be not retained ? @GaurangDhorda

Comment: If multiple rows can be retained , i can support you on your link . Its retaining only single row as of now . I tried looping through values but that didnt help .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-5hbcir?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.ts here is updated link check it out :)

Comment: Amazing , that works . Please add it as an answer to , so that i can upvote you . Also i am supporting you on your link